# Mockito.mockConstruction does not return the mocked object in the tested class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write missing tests for an capacitor android plugin written in Java that uses google's AdMob lib.

The function I am trying to testing has a `new AdView()` call that is returning `null` even when the constructor is mocked with [Mockito's object construction mock](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction) and I am not quite sure why.

I try to create a new `AdView` inside the test threat and it works.

This is the current test (it does not have any assert yet because I am just trying to pass the view creation:

```java
    @Test
    public void npa_requests_for_banner_when_specified_inside_options() {
        sut = new AdMob();
        try (MockedStatic<AdOptions> adOptionsStaticMocked = Mockito.mockStatic(AdOptions.class)) {
            adOptionsStaticMocked.when(AdOptions::getFactory).thenReturn(adOptionsFactoryMock);
            
            try (MockedConstruction<AdView> adViewMocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(AdView.class)) {
                Context mockedContext = mock(Context.class);
                AdView adView = new AdView(mockedContext);


                sut.showBanner(pluginCallMock);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the `showBanner` relevant code:

```java
  @PluginMethod
  public void showBanner(PluginCall call) {

    if (mAdView != null) {
      return;
    }

    final AdOptions adOptions = AdOptions
      .getFactory()
      .createBannerOptions(call);

    setTestDevicesIfNeeded(adOptions.isTesting);

    try {
      mAdView = new AdView(getContext()); // THIS BREAKS! NO MOCK IS RETURNED
      mAdView.setAdSize(adOptions.adSize.size);
        
      mAdViewLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
      mAdViewLayout.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      mAdViewLayout.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

      // More Code here...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      call.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    }
  }
```

The `mAdView = new AdView(getContext())` part is where the code breaks.

Does anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps someone new in Capacitor plugins in Java like me.

The problem was that `getContext()` returned null... What I did was:

```java
    @Test
    public void npa_requests_for_banner_when_specified_inside_options() {
        sut = new AdMob() {
            @Override
            public Context getContext() {
                return mockedContext;
            }
        };
        try (MockedStatic<AdOptions> adOptionsStaticMocked = Mockito.mockStatic(AdOptions.class)) {
            adOptionsStaticMocked.when(AdOptions::getFactory).thenReturn(adOptionsFactoryMock);
            
            try (MockedConstruction<AdView> adViewMocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(AdView.class)) {
                Context mockedContext = mock(Context.class);
                AdView adView = new AdView(mockedContext);


                sut.showBanner(pluginCallMock);
            }
        }
    }
```